# iPhone - Last row not visible UITableView in iPhone 4 and 3GS

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am using `UITableView` ,It is working perfect in iPhone 5 but last row is not visible in iPhone 4 and 3GS on IOS 7 & as well as lower versions.

I am using **auto layout** mode, still the problem persists.

Last row is visible if i scroll and hold.

I think the problem might be that the height of table view is greater than size of the screen.

Comment: The uitableview frame height is probably not being adjusted correctly. Check the constraints.

Comment: I also have some trouble with IOS 7 height issue, i guess you should set the frame using screen Bound and you will be good

Comment: What are your constraints ?? How are they defined ??

Comment: @iRaviiVooda i have not set any constraints

Comment: Autolayout is not simply "a mode" - you have to set constraints for it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have said you are just not resizing your view correctly on 3.5 inch devices.

You probably don't have the proper autoresizing masks set. Try to set the mask to just

```
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight.
```